# In app billing and upload an application on google play whole process?

Tags: android

i have develop an application . i have implemented in app billing in it. i want to upload application on Google play.as i have uploaded one apk with one of key store . but it is deleted by mistake. i want to remove existing apk and upload new apk with new key store. Please help me in this process. any help will be appreciated.

application not publish yet. if i deletes it then can i  create new application with same name and same package name.

Comment: any suggestion will help ful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the old application from google play and create new application with newly generated keystore.

If you are using newly generated key, google play consider as new application.

The disadvantage of losing old key store is you can loss all the google play history(Download count,user comments).

Comment: Thank you for responding. but i have one more query . my application is not published yet. there is any solution in that case ? and in other case if i deleted this application then new application can be with same name and same package name .please respond me as soon as possible.  i have stuck in it since last week.

Comment: case 1:if your application is not published in google play, you can generate as many as new keystores, just backup latest submission keystore.

Comment: What do you mean by backup latest submission keystore? The last keystore is deleted by me and when I am trying to upload the new apk file with new keystore then Google paly do not allowing me due to different signature. As I mentioned, My app did not publish yet and I was just trying to upload new apk in alpha testing mode. Please provide the solution. Thanks \

Comment: backup means store in SVN server..if your application is not published then it is in draft mode, in this case you can delete the old apk and update with new apk (no need to change the package and app name here)....if your application is pubished,delete old apk and  add new apk with newly generated keystore(need to changed app name and package name here)

Comment: yes, but i am unable to delete apk which is in draft mode. how can i delete this.

Comment: In Google play Developer console see top right corner, click on Draft>Delete this app.

Comment: this one delete app not apk . i want to just delete apk.

Comment: Draft>Delete this app is only option google provided to reset the apk incase of keystore change.

Comment: if we use this option then we can create app with same name again?

Comment: yeah..create the same name again.you need to provide all the details about the app..it is like a new application.